# Components and ColdFusion 8

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I wrote a cfc to handle all of the functions for one aspect of a project.  I typically write in tags but chose to learn something new so I wrote it in script.  All my workup and testing was done on a CommandBox running Lucee for  quick spin up and a dev environment.  It worked like a charm.  Now when I uploaded it to our production server running ACF 8 it will not read any of the file.  I navigate to the address of the cfc and where it would typically display the functions that are accessible I get the code in a paragraph.

Before I rewrite this in tags I want to make sure that it is a compatibility issue with ACF 8 and not my code and/or any work a rounds.  Please do not hammer me for not using params.

Here is my code:

```
component {
    DSN = 'xxxx';

    public function init(){
    }


    remote function BranchContact(MainContactID, BranchOfContactID, UserID) returnformat="plain"{

        data = IsBranch(BranchOfContactID);

        if(data.branchTotal == 0){
            // result = 'no branches';
            result = InsertBranch(MainContactID, BranchOfContactID, UserID);    
            //WriteBranchingHistory(MainContactID, BranchOfContactID, UserID);      
            result = 1;
        }
        else{
            // message = 'It appears that you are branching to an account is already a branch - from component';
            queryString = 'Select top 1 ParentCID from branches where ChildCID =' & BranchOfContactID;
            data = RunQuery(queryString);
            result = data.ParentCID;
        }
        return result;

    }

    private function IsBranch(BranchOfContactID){
        queryString = 'Select count(*) as branchTotal from branches where ChildCID = ' & BranchOfContactID;
        RunQuery(queryString);
        return data;
    }

    private function InsertBranch(ParentCID, ChildCID, UserID){
        // try{         
            queryString = 'Insert into Branches (ParentCID,  ChildCID, UserID) values (' & ChildCID  & ', ' & ParentCID & ', '& UserID & ')';
            data = RunQuery(queryString);
            //WriteBranchingHistory(MainContactID, BranchOfContactID, UserID);
            //need to write the branching history to the contact history table so that is can be tracked
            contactResultsID = 102;
            note = 'Account branched to - ' & ChildCID;
            quotedNote = ''''&note&'''';
            activityType = 'Branched';
            quotedActivity = ''''&activityType&'''';
            campaignID = 0;
            today = 'getdate()';

            AddContactHistory(ParentCID, today, contactresultsID, UserID, quotedActivity, quotedNote, campaignID);
            //return history;
            return data;
        // }
        // catch(e){
        //  errorMessage = 'While trying to branch account';
        //  message = error(errorMessage);
        //  return message;
        // }

    }

    remote function Delete(ChildCID, UserID) returnformat="plain"{
        // try{
            //have to use a query to get the parentcid since it will be empty when the ajax query is triggered
            Parent = GetParent(ChildCID);
            queryString = 'Delete from branches where ChildCID = ' & ChildCID;
            data = RunQuery(queryString);
            //WriteBranchingHistory(MainContactID, BranchOfContactID, UserID)

            contactResultsID = 103;
            note = 'Account unbranched from - ' & Parent.parentCID;
            quotedNote = ''''&note&'''';
            activityType = 'Removed Branch';
            quotedActivity = ''''&activityType&'''';
            campaignID = 0;
            today = 'getdate()';

            AddContactHistory(ChildCID, today, contactresultsID, UserID, quotedActivity, quotedNote, campaignID);




            return data;
        // }
        // catch(e){
        //  errorMessage = 'While trying to delete branching';
        //  message = error(errorMessage);
        //  return e;
        // }


    }

    private function Update(){

    }

    <!--- WriteBranchHistory has not been completed 
    public function WriteBranchingHistory(MainContactID, BranchOfContactID, UserID) returnformat="plain"{


        try{
            queryString = 'insert into BranchHistory(contactID, ChildContactID, UserID, InsertDate) values
             ('& MainContactiD &', '& BranchContactID & ', ' & UserID & ', getdate());';
            data = RunQuery(queryString);
            // return data;
            //oldMar = GetOldMar(MainContactID);
            // writeDump(oldMar);
            // writeDump(queryString);
            //return oldMar;

        }
        catch(e){
            errorMessage = 'While trying to add branch history';
            message = error(errorMessage);
            return message;
        }

    }

    --->

    public function GetParent(ChildCID) returnformat="html"{

        queryString = 'Select top 1 parentCID from branches where childCID =  ' & ChildCID;
        data = RunQuery(queryString);
        return data;
    }

    public function GetUserInfo(userid){
        myQuery = new Query();
        myQuery.addParam(name="userid", value=userid, cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric");
        myQuery.setDataSource(DSN);
        myQuery.setSQL('select * from users where userid = :userid');
        data = myQuery.execute().getResult();
        return data;

    }

    private function RunQuery(queryString){
        myQuery = new Query();
        // myQuery.addParam(name="ContactID", value=ContactID, cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric");
        myQuery.setDataSource(DSN);
        myQuery.setSQL(queryString);
        data = myQuery.execute().getResult();
        return data;
    }

    private function error(errorMessage){
        message = "Oops something went wrong <br/>" & errorMessage;
        return message;
    }

    private function AddContactHistory(ParentCID, today, contactresultsID, UserID, quotedActivity, quotedNote, campaignID) {
        InsertHistoryString = 'insert into contacthistory (contactid, historydate, contactresultID, userid, activitytype, note, campaignID) values 
                ('&ParentCID& ', ' &today& ', ' &contactresultsID& ', ' &UserID& ', ' &quotedActivity& ', ' &quotedNote& ', ' &CampaignID& ');';
        InsertHistory = RunQuery(InsertHistoryString);

    }

}
```

Comment: You've got your answer, but as a rule: don't develop on a different platform and/or version from that which you deploy.

Comment: I typically do not but our system is ACF 8 and we do not have a dev environment and no budget to have one created. Plus it being 2015 its hard to find a cfml engine that is that old.  Decided on running commandbox with lucee as testing so that I could just run from my system.  I did see last night as I was poking around the Lucee admin that I might be able to set it to an earlier version, but need to ask Brad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`component` was not supported in cfscript until CF9, so yes, this is a compatibility issue.

Pete Freitag on his blog has a good cheatsheet for cfscript compatability, linked here: https://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/coldfusion/cfscript/